# Gson Reader can be readed only once?

Tags: android, gson, json

I'm doing some tests with Gson parser to Json objects and object model.
There is one thing that I can't understand, why Reader can read once?

Code example:

```
Reader targetReader = new StringReader(jdb);

String targetString = "";

try {
    int intValueOfChar;
    while ((intValueOfChar = reader.read()) != -1) {
        targetString += (char) intValueOfChar;
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jason = jp.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();

JsonArray votes_a = jason.getAsJsonArray("votesA");
JsonArray votes_b = jason.getAsJsonArray("votesB");
```

In this code the first while goes perfect, reads and writes to String but then I want to read it and parset to Object but the reader is empty!!

is there a way to keep the information, and recycle it? 
Do I have to clone it before? how?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you read from the reader, it moves a pointer along what you're reading.  So after reading through it once, you're already at the end of what you're reading.  Take a look at [the reset() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#reset()) of StringReader.

Comment: Perfect, I will give it a try! and see what happens.

Comment: does not work, gives me IOException. And tried to set a mark and the same exception